# Pass request user's username to Serializer from Viewset in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to pass the username of the logged in user from ListCreateAPIView to ModelSerializer to use object with same PrimaryKey from Clients model as a default, but i don't understand how to do it correctly.

In views.py:

```py
class CartAPIList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Clientcarts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, )
```

In serializers.py:

```py
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client_id = serializers.HiddenField(default=Clients.objects.get(pk="username"))

    class Meta:
        model = Clientcarts
        fields = '__all__'
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Is `Clients` your user model?

Comment: Yes, but logged in users may not be in Clients table. So I want to allow only users that are in Clients table to do POST requests

Comment: how exactly can these be logged in without being in the `Client`s table? If `Client`s is the user model?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't usnderstand you correctly. Clients is my custom table and it's not user model

Answer (score 0):

Pass `context = {'user': request.user}` as argument in your serializer class in `views.py` file.

Then you can use context value in `CartSerializer` in `serializers.py` file as:

```
user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_user(self, obj):
    user = self.context.get('user')
    return user
```